# How to filter down an array of arrays based on a couple of rules

Tags: javascript

I have the following dataset as an example:

```
const labels = [
  ['Wed', '11 PM'],
  ['Thu', '12 AM'],
  ['Thu', '1 AM'],
  ['Thu', '2 AM'],
  ['Thu', '3 AM'],
  ['Thu', '4 AM'],
  ['Thu', '5 AM'],
  ['Thu', '6 AM'],
];
```

I'm trying to filter this down to keep every nth hour based on data array size, replace the others with empty strings. I'm then trying to only keep the first instance of a day that has a time.

Desired output:

```
[
  ['Wed', '11 PM'],
  ['', ''],
  ['Thu', '1 AM'],
  ['', ''],
  ['', '3 AM'],
  ['', ''],
  ['', '5 AM'],
  ['', ''],
];
```

I tried to do this with a simple for-loop to go through and check if the previous array item's day matched the current one in the iteration, but that didn't work since it will make a string blank, then the next one would be compared to the blank string instead of the original day value.

I think I need to keep track of the first instance of days somewhere outside the loop and then compare against that so it's not changing the original array as it goes?

```
const labels = [
  ['Wed', '11 PM'],
  ['Thu', '12 AM'],
  ['Thu', '1 AM'],
  ['Thu', '2 AM'],
  ['Thu', '3 AM'],
  ['Thu', '4 AM'],
  ['Thu', '5 AM'],
  ['Thu', '6 AM'],
];

// Want to keep every nth hour, make others empty strings

// Want to keep only the first instance of a day name  that has a time and change the rest of the day names to be empty strings

// Desired output:
// [
//   ['Wed', '11 PM'],
//   ['', ''],
//   ['Thu', '1 AM'],
//   ['', ''],
//   ['', '3 AM'],
//   ['', ''],
//   ['', '5 AM'],
//   ['', ''],
// ];

function hoursLabelInterval(hours) {
  if (hours <= 6) {
    return 1;
  } else if (hours <= 12) {
    return 2;
  } else if (hours <= 24) {
    return 4;
  } else if (hours <= 36) {
    return 6;
  } else if (hours <= 48) {
    return 8;
  } else if (hours <= 60) {
    return 10;
  } else if (hours <= 72) {
    return 12;
  } else {
    return 24;
  }
}
function formatXLabels(labels, hoursToSkip) {
  let result = labels;
  for (let i=1; i<labels.length; i++) {
    if (i%hoursToSkip !== 0) {
      result[i][1] = '';
    }
  }
  console.log(result);
}

formatXLabels(labels, hoursLabelInterval(labels.length));
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could do something like this:

```js
const labels = [
    ['Wed', '11 PM'],
    ['Thu', '12 AM'],
    ['Thu', '1 AM'],
    ['Thu', '2 AM'],
    ['Thu', '3 AM'],
    ['Thu', '4 AM'],
    ['Thu', '5 AM'],
    ['Thu', '6 AM'],
];
let currentDay = '';
const newLabels = labels.map((label, i) => {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
        if (label[0] !== currentDay) {
         currentDay = label[0];
            return [label[0], label[1]]
     }
        return ['', label[1]]
    }
    return ['','']
});

console.log(newLabels);
```

Comment: If you click on `<>` in answer editor you can cut/paste this code into a "stack snippet" to make it runnable right here in the page and anyone can quickly see the logged results

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks, will definitely start using this more often!